# CSS Styles AWOL After Applying Animations

Tags: css, animation

1. Yes, it's a novice question
2. Yes, I tried to research it

Ok. Here's the link to the code...
    [Codepen](http://codepen.io/ikemikek/pen/pgQRZa).

```
<div class="feature container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>Welcome to Keller Compensation & HR!</h1>
        <p>Focusing on providing comprehensive compensation and human resources services <br>for small and mid-size companies in a variety of industries.</p>
        <div id="getstarted">
            <a href="#">Get Started</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, my `.get started a` is supposed to have a border around it. And it did, until I added an animation. I'd like to retain that during the animation and after.

Comment: I cant see the border in Codepen even at the very first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had an extra "}" before .feature #getstarted a

This should work:

```
.feature {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.feature #getstarted {
  margin-top: 40px;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: getstrted;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode:
}


/* it was here */
.feature #getstarted a {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 4px solid;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.feature a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes getstrted {
  0% {
    left: -900px
  }

  100% {
    left: 0px
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your time! Perfect!